# Please help identify this Ausini piece

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

The one that looks like a rocket head or a projectile tip. I hoped there was a corresponding LEGO piece. There is no inventory on the instructions.

[image]

Comment: I caanot identify this piece. Are you sure instructions are for LEGO set? What is the number of this set?

Comment: it's not Lego, it's the Ausini Rifle https://bricker.info/osets/Ausini/P22002/

Comment: What kind of information do you expect? As far as I know, the Ausini brand has no public parts database or identification schema like with the LEGO part IDs. Therefore I doubt anyone can tell you more than "the rifle cartridge piece". If you have the instruction manual or the box, you could check them to see if they have a complete inventory listing with numbers, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I hoped there was a corresponding Lego piece. No there is no inventory on the instructions. I'll have to ask to the seller to ship the piece. Thx anyway.

Comment: Maybe they can put a Friends lipstick (part# 93094c01) inside a Technic pin stud (part# 4274) and pretend they're tracer rounds? LOL xD  I mean... it might work?

Answer (score 2):

Even though there's no corresponding *LEGO* piece, you could get away with this substitution:

[image]

*[Part #89522 - Horn (Unicorn).](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=93485#T=C&C=95)*

This is how it would look with the pieces you have, and color wise the Horn comes in metallic silver too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Bar with Light Cover (Bulb) / Bionicle Barraki Eye](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58176#T=C) is close to the shape you are looking for. Can be placed over the round 1 x 1 brick. It comes in Light Bluish Gray color too.

[image]